# Keep array elements if key is found in flat whitelist array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-intersect

How can I succeed to filter a multidimensional with a help of other array value as keys for the first array.

```
$multidimensional = [
    ['var1' => 'val1'],
    ['var2' => 'val2'],
    ['var3' => 'val3'],
    ['val4' => 'val4'],
];
$filter = [1, 3];
```

The final result should be:

```
$multidimensional = [
    1 => ['var2' => 'val2'],
    3 => ['val4' => 'val4']
];
```

It should be something similar to `array_slice()` or some other method. How can I easily perform such a task?

Comment: [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) function:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($multidimensional, array_flip($filter));
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon my comment with a small example

```
<?php

$arrayOne = [
    1 => ['foo' => 'bar'],
    2 => ['foo' => 'bar'],
    3 => ['foo' => 'bar'],
    4 => ['foo' => 'bar'],
];

$arrayTwo = [1 => [], 3 => []];

print_r(array_intersect_key($arrayOne, $arrayTwo));
```

see [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) on php.net

Answer (score 1):

Another variation using `array_diff_key` and `array_flip` functions:

```
$multidimensional = array_diff_key($multidimensional, array_diff_key($multidimensional, array_flip($filter)));

print_r($multidimensional);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [var2] => val2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [val4] => val4
        )
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php